# how to mass delete with regex

Tags: regex

I have a lot of incoming emails
and I want to save all in notepad

```
    checkzone@anagram
    12:56 AM (7 hours ago)

    to me 
    Live => example1@gmail.com | example1

    checkzone@anagram
    6:31 AM (2 hours ago)

    to me 
    Live => example2@gmail.com | example2

    checkzone@anagram
    6:31 AM (1 hours ago)

    to me 
    Live => example3@gmail.com | example3
```

so it becomes like this

```
Live => example1@gmail.com | example1
Live => example2@gmail.com | example2
Live => example3@gmail.com | example3
```

how to delete all

```
checkzone@anagram
6:31 AM (1 hours ago)

to me
```

with regex!

question
What code should be used when using regex?
please with demo regex101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
[\s\S]*?(Live.*$)
```

With the replacement string:

```
$1\n
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dE2iH7/2)**

[image]

Comment: @YogaTheÐevil's-NoCry glad to help